# How to load a SavedModel in a new Colab notebook?

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colab. 
In a first notebook, I saved my model using: `model.save('my_model.h5')`.
In the same notebook, I can see that the model is stored. 
Input: `ls -d $PWD/*`
Output: `/content/my_model.h5`

In the same notebook, I can restore the saved model by using: 
`model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5')`

But if I want to load the same model in a new notebook, I got an error message.
Input:

```py
from keras.models import load_model
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/my_model.h5')
```

Error message:

> OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: /content/my_model.h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

Thanks for your help,

Boris

Answer (score 0):

Each notebook is on a different machine. You need to save it on google drive, using drive.mount("drive"). Then you can share the model across different notebooks.

Comment: I tried. Here is the error msg I get: OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = '/content/drive/My\ Drive/model_du_jour.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 13, o_flags = 242)

Comment: I used this to mount: from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

Comment: You can create it in '/content' first, then move the file with `!mv model_du_jour.h5 "/content/drive/My Drive/"`